# Testing a list is sorted in the correct order capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

I'm trying to write some tests in capybara that will test a list of dates are sorted correctly. For example I have a list of dates Wed 27 Jun 12, Mon 13 Aug 12, Thu 31 May 12 and when I click on the button it will rearrange the dates starting from the earliest *ie:* Thu 31 May 12, Wed 27 Jun 12, 13 Aug 12.

Is there any way in capybara that you can write such tests.

Normally I would use methods like page.find etc but those methods will just find the dates and not tell you if they have been sorted in the correct order.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use the `:nth-child` css selector.

Lets say your list of dates are in a `<ul>` with the id `#dates`, you could test order with:

```
page.should have_selector("ul#dates li:nth-child(1)", content: @date1.content)
page.should have_selector("ul#dates li:nth-child(2)", content: @date2.content)
```

The first value passed into `have_selector()` is your selector, the second (in this example) is the content you expect. You're not limited to passing just content for example if each date linked to the `Date#show` action you could add `url: date_path(@date)`.

Comment: Had the same error. Great answer above but need to use one of the following: invalid keys :content, should be one of :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum, :exact, :match, :wait